# SMS Delivery Reports not received by gammu on Teltonika TRM250 / Quectel BG96

Tags: sms, at-command, gammu

I have a Teltonika TRM250 USB cellular modem connected to Linux computer running gammu-smsd 1.42. SMS sending and receiving are working fine, but I can't get SMS delivery reports to work. I have set DeliveryReport = log in my configuration file, the sent items have status "DeliveryOK" and even my Telco confirms they see delivery report requested.

However, after sending the SMS, nothing in the log indicates anything is received.

How should I proceed debugging this?

I suspect the modem might need some additional initialization commands, but have not been able to find anything.
As I understand, it's basically a Quectel BG96 with a USB - serial converter, here's the AT commands manual:
https://wiki.teltonika-networks.com/wikibase/images/4/48/Quectel_BG96_AT_Commands_Manual_V2.3.pdf

My config file:

```
[gammu]
device = /dev/ttyUSB2
connection = at115200
synchronizetime = no
logformat = nothing

[smsd]
Service = sql
Driver = native_mysql
LogFile = syslog
DebugLevel = 255
DeliveryReport = log 
SMSC = +xxxxxx
StatusFrequency = 300
ReceiveFrequency = 60
User = xxx
Password = xxx
Host = localhost
Database = xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the TRM250 just does not support delivery reports (although Teltonika has not confirmed this).
After upgrading the firmware to BG96MAR02A07M1G_01.007.01.007 and RMA-ing the modem with no results, I exchanged for TRM240 (firmware EC21ECGAR06A04M1G_01.004.01.004), which is based on a different chip (Quectel EC21) and works.

Here are the AT commands (provided by Teltonika) to send an SMS in text mode and request delivery report:

```
AT+CNMI=2,1,2,1,0                                                                                           
OK
AT+CSMP=49,167,0,0 
OK
AT+CMGF=1
OK
AT+CMGS="+xxxxxxxxx"
> testtest
> 
+CMGS: 72

OK

+CDS: 6,72,"+xxxxxxxxx",145,"22/02/23,18:11:00+08","22/02/23,18:11:00+08",0
```

The +CDS line is the report - received correctly on TRM240, but nothing on TRM250.